# error struct undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, struct

I have used structs in my code. As everything seems alright, I am not quite sure why it is producing this error. I feel I have clearly declared the struct operators. Still I keep getting the following error:

```
operators undeclared (first use in this function)
```

**This is my code:**

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "input.h"
    #include "operations.h"

    typedef int (*arithmeticFcn)(int, int);


    struct operators
    {
        char symbol;
        char opName[10];
        arithmeticFcn fcn;
    };

    int main() 
    {
        int opNum, res;

        struct operators calc[4] = 
        {
            {'+', "Add", addition},
            {'-', "Subtract", subtract},
            {'*', "Multiply", multiply},
            {'/', "Divide", divide}
        };

        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) 
        {
            int j= rand() % 4;
            struct operators temp = calc[i];
            operators[i] = calc[j];
            calc[j] = temp;
            printf("%d or %s: %s", i, operators.symbol, operators.opName);
        }

        printf("Enter Hotkey: ");
        scanf("%i || &c", &opNum, &operators.symbol);
        res = (operators[opNum || operators.symbol]) (op1, op2);

        printf("%i %c %i = %i", op1, operators.symbol, op2, res);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your indentation doesn't help tracking the problem for sure. You should try to improve the quality of your questions.

Comment: The assignment `operators[i] = calc[j];` is giving you the error — you don't have a variable called `operators`.

Comment: yes but without it how do i shuffle the struct?

Comment: By the looks of it, that line should read `calc[i] = calc[j];` — but you'll need to fix other code later (the `scanf()` for instance).  Also, I don't think `operators[opNum || operators.symbol]` does what you think it does; you'll only execute entry `0` or `1` in the array.

Comment: Under `struct operators calc = ...` add `struct operators operators[4];`

Comment: you could also do `typedef struct { ... } operators;` which is how I would do it

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that fixed the issue... Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes i do have a few more errors with the code, still trying to figure it out

Comment: When your posted code contains 'home grown' header files, be sure to post the contents of those 'home grown' header files